# watch browser's history clear action using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, local-storage

I found a logic that listens to change in localstorage data and throws a trigger when a particular item is deleted from localstorage.

```
$(window).bind('storage', function(e) {
    if ((e.originalEvent.key === null && e.originalEvent.newValue == null) || (e.originalEvent.key === 'mockUserData' && e.originalEvent.newValue == null)) {
      $state.go('signUp');
    }
});
```

It works perfectly in chrome. When I clear the browsers cache and data, my page has already navigated to login page automatically. But somehow this same piece of code doesn't work in mozilla or safari.

Can anyone help me fix this issue for firefox and safari? What I am trying to do is, when the user clears his browsers' cache/data/history, I want my page to change state automatically without the user manually refreshing the page

Thanks

Comment: May not be any event triggered for that in all browsers perhaps. Where are you using this?

Comment: I am using this logic when the my angular controller is initialized. in the very beginning. But if event was not triggered, then I shouldn't have worked in chrome as well, right

Comment: No, you are assuming that all browsers handle clearing of cache the same. You are nearing areas where privacy policies may differ. Would need to read specs for this. Is an event really needed? Or just check if storage item exists?

Comment: But in order to check if storage item exists, some activity might be needed from user's side, like making a server call which use a token or some value from the storage. Is there any way to do this check automatically? Like periodically checking the localstorage item? Will this periodic check be a logical and practical solution?